# Meaning of Matlab Notation: xx@yy

Tags: matlab, handle, notation

I'm having trouble understanding the following code snippet. The simple call looks like this, without any assignment or else:

```
expression1@expression2;
```

`expression2` is referring to a self defined handle class.

I've looked into handles but couldn't figure out what the given calling structure does, from the normal examples `@(x) x^2;` or `f = @sin;`and couldn't find similar examples online.

Any help on what the notation might do is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without context it's hard to say for sure, but this looks like a subclass calling the superclass method (usually before additional functionality in the subclass implementation)...

See the docs [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-superclass-methods-and-properties.html).

Example from the linked docs:

```
classdef Sub < Super
   methods
      function foo(obj)
         % preprocessing steps
          ...
         foo@Super(obj);
         % postprocessing steps
          ...
      end
   end
end
```

In this case, the `foo` function is defined in the `Super` class, implemented in the subclass `Sub`, and extended (with preprocessing and postprocessing). The `foo@Super(obj)` notation calls the superclass method from the subclass.

Note that this is analogous to `SuperObj.foo(obj)`, except you don't have an instantiated object (`SuperObj`) of class `Super` to make this call. And since you're extending / overriding the superclass version of the function, you can't just call `obj.foo()` as you would if the subclass implementation was identical - that's the function you're already in! Hence the need for this different notation.